# Typescript "Cannot assign to property, because it is a constant or read-only" even though property is not marked readonly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, readonly

I have the following code

```
type SetupProps = {
    defaults: string;
}

export class Setup extends React.Component<SetupProps, SetupState> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.props.defaults = "Whatever";
}
```

When trying to run this code the TS compiler returns the following error:

> Cannot assign to 'defaults' because it is a constant or a read-only
>   property.

How is `deafualts` a readonly property, when its clearly not marked this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're extending `React.Component` and it defines `props` as `Readonly<SetupProps>`

```
class Component<P, S> {
    constructor(props: P, context?: any);
    ...
    props: Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode }> & Readonly<P>;
    state: Readonly<S>;
    ...
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L296)

If you want to assign some default values, you can go with something like:

```
constructor({ defaults = 'Whatever' }: Partial<SetupProps>) {
    super({defaults});
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. But how am I then going to be able to modify (assign)  any of the values of my props object.

Comment: Added an example. Hope that helps